# How to prevent dragging an element outside of its div container?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function that allows me to drag an element to a new position. However, I can erroneously drag elements outside of my div container and into the edge of the viewport, causing scroll bars to appear. How would I modify this function to stop dragging the element when it hits the edge of its parent div?

```
function dragElement(element) {
    let pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

    if (document.getElementById(element.id + "-header")) {
        // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
        document.getElementById(element.id + "-header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
        // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
        element.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        element.style.top = (element.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        element.style.left = (element.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        // stop moving when mouse button is released:
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just use `overflow:hidden;` in CSS, but then you can drag items to where you no longer see them... I would do that anyways, unless you have a good reason otherwise.

Comment: None of these helped when you searched for them? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+drag+constrain+to+element